# unable to build qt gui packadges: catkin_make must be invoked in the root of workspace

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Newbie to ROS, I have downloaded "qt_gui_core" under my "ros_ws" (/ros_ws/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_core) and complied with cmake ./CMakeLists.txt successfully. When I try to run catkin_make to build I get the error message:
The specified base path "/ros_ws/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_core" contains a package but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace.

What am I doing wrong? How is one supposed to compile these packages without a catkin_ws and under ros_ws? also, qt_gui_core contains many subdirectories (qt_dotgraph, qt_gui_cpp...) am I correct by assuming the get built if I successfully build qt_gui_core/qt_gui_core?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239170/unable-to-build-qt-gui-packadges:-catkin_make-must-be-invoked-in-the-root-of-workspace/) by [sadisari](https://answers.ros.org/users/27443/sadisari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) on how to create a proper workspace for ROS/catkin.

Note that there is no difference between a ROS workspace and a catkin workspace.
The layout for a workspace is typically `<PATH_TO_ROOT>/src/<PACKAGES>`.
Choose `<PATH_TO_ROOT>` how you see fit, put all packages in the `src` folder below (in your case, the `qt_gui_core` package). You can have multiple packages in `src`.

Before you compile, go to the  `src` directory and call `catkin_init_workspace`, remember to call `source /opt/ros/<DISTRO>/setup.bash` (where `<DISTRO>` is `indigo`, `jade`, `kinetic`, whatever you have).

You don't need to call `cmake` manually, `catkin_make` will do that.

After you compiled, call `source <PATH_TO_ROOT>/devel/setup.bash` after compilation to actually use this workspace.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-11**:\

> Before you compile, go to the src directory and call `catkin_init_workspace` [..]

That's not actually necessary: `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) will do that automatically for you.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-07-11**:
@gvdhoorn, really? Nice. Didn't know that ;-)